# reshape table in mariadb

Tags: sql, mariadb, pivot-table, reshape, entity-attribute-value

How can I reshape a SQL table (mariadb ) of:

```
vehicle_id attr_id, attr_value
1   123 BMW
1   345 SERIES 3
1   678 manual
```

to:

```
vehicle_id, make, description, gearbox
1         , BMW , SERIES 3   , manual
```

A regular:

```
SELECT vehicle_id, max(attr_value) FROM car_table group by vehicle_id;

vehicle_id, max(attr_value)
13086520180701  SERIES 3
```

and `PIVOT` does not seem to be available (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/pivoting-in-mariadb/

Comment: How do you know which attr_id is make , which attr_id is description and which one is gearbox? Or question is about above static values?

Comment: It is not constant. And group is key, value pairs

Comment: So how do you know that attr_id = 123 BMW goes to "make" column, and not to "description"?

Comment: Good question. I would love to have something like https://databricks.com/blog/2016/02/09/reshaping-data-with-pivot-in-apache-spark.html naming of the columns can be handled as a second step. For an individual group the key, value pairs are assume to appear only a single time.

Comment: It's usually called `model` not `description`.

Comment: The transformation is called "pivoting".

Answer (score 0):

You can try using conditional aggregation

```
SELECT 
    vehicle_id, 
    max(case when attr_id=123 then attr_value) as make,
    max(case when attr_id=345 then attr_value) as description,
    max(case when attr_id=678 then attr_value) as gearbox
FROM car_table 
group by vehicle_id;
```

Comment: Downvoted, because its clear that attr_id values are not constant since it is a table data. We should verify it before answering. If values were constant then I would downvote the question.

Answer (score -1):

If the `attr_id` values are always identical for `make, description, gearbox` you can achieve required result with the below query:

```
select make.vehicle_id  , 
make.attr_value as make ,
description.attr_value as description ,
gearbox.attr_value as gearbox 
from 
car_table make,  
car_table description, 
car_table gearbox 
where make.vehicle_id = description.vehicle_id 
and description.vehicle_id = gearbox.vehicle_id 
and make.attr_id = 123 
and description.attr_id = 345 
and gearbox.attr_id = 678
```

Comment: Downvoted, because its clear that attr_id values are not constant since it is a table data. We should verify it before answering. If values were constant then I would downvote the question.